# 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on creating a thumbnail image. In my Application, I am using FileUpload Control to upload an image. I am using 3 tier architecture.
how to generate image file I am using C# language with asp.net

Here is my code.

```
 public string CreateThumbnail(int maxWidth, int maxHeight, string path)
    {

        var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
        var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);

        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        image.Dispose();

        string fileRelativePath = "newsizeimages/" + maxWidth + Path.GetFileName(path);
        newImage.Save(Server.MapPath(fileRelativePath), newImage.RawFormat);
        return fileRelativePath;
    }

    protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductImages productImage = new ProductImages();
        productImage.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(ProductDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());

        if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            MessageLabel1.Text = "Please Select Image File";    //checking if file uploader has no file selected
        }
        else
        {
            int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            productImage.ProductImage = new byte[length];

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(productImage.ProductImage, 0, length);

            try
            {
                productImage.ProductImage.ImageUrl = CreateThumbnail(32, 32, Server.MapPath("Images/UserImage/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

                ProductImageBL.AddProductImages(productImage);
                MessageLabel1.Text = "Product Image has been successfully added!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageLabel1.Text = "Some error occured while processing the request. Error Description <br/>" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

ProductImages class:

```
public class ProductImages
{
    public int ProductImagesID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You're assigning `ProductImage` to a byte array ? Does a byte array have an `ImageUrl ` property ? Not as far as I Know !

Comment: Yes. Where shall i make change?

Comment: I don't know your `ProductImages` class, but maybe you want to assign `productImage.ImageUrl` instead of `productImage.ProductImage.ImageUrl`? BTW you should reconsider your naming. You have a class named `ProductImages` with a property named `ProductImage` and an instance of that class `productImage`. At least to me that's quite confusing.

Comment: @derpirscher Can you check updated code? I have added productImages class

Comment: Where is ImageUrl property defined?

Comment: @orion You don't have an `ImageUrl` property defined anywhere. So you can't assign it. I suggest adding it to the `ProductImages` class and then assign via `productImage.ImageUrl = ...`